# Improving a Python Wrapper for C code using c_types

Tags: python, c, ctypes, wrapper

I am working on a simple wrapper for C code on Python using c_types.

My problem is the following :

In the Python code, for what I understand, I create a variable named args used to marshal data type from python to C. My problem is I have to enter each argument
`(str.encode(sys.argv[0]), str.encode(sys.argv[1]), ...)` which is ... unPythonic.

What if I don't know how many argument will be entered in my function, like with optionnal arguments ?

**I already tried this:**

```
   args=(ctypes.c_char_p * (len(sys.argv)))(str.encode(" ".join(sys.argv)))
```

However it put all arguments in the first one, meaning argv[0]="pyclib.py 1 2 3 4"
So, does anyone have an idea to help me ?
Thank you for your time.
Here is what it looks like for now :

**Python code :**

```
import signal
import ctypes 
import os 
import sys 

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    print("==================")
    print("Begining of Python program")
    print("==================")
    
    # Retrieving paht for .so file
    libname = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"clib.so"))

    # Setting argtypes and return types for C function
    LIBC = ctypes.CDLL(libname)
    LIBC.main.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p),]
    LIBC.main.restypes=[ctypes.c_int,]

    # Setting argtypes 
    args=(ctypes.c_char_p * (len(sys.argv)))(str.encode(sys.argv[0]),str.encode(sys.argv[1]),str.encode(sys.argv[2])) #QUESTION

    # Creating status variable which will be used to get exit code of C called function
    status = LIBC.main(len(args),args)

    # Printing exit code 
    print("C function exit code : ", status)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,signal.SIG_DFL)
    input()

    print("==================")
    print("End of Python program")
    print("==================")
```

**C Code :**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>


volatile sig_atomic_t flag = 0 ;

void raise_flag(int sig)
{
    flag=1;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("\n==================\n");
    printf("Begining of C program\n");
    printf("=================\n");
    
    signal(SIGINT,raise_flag);

        printf("argc :%i \n",argc);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < argc ; i++ )
    {
        printf("Argument %i is %s \n", (i+1), argv[i]) ;
    }
printf("=========\n");
printf("End of C program\n");
printf("========\n");
 return 0 ;

}
```

**Makefile :**

```
all: test

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.so *.html

clib.so: clib.o
    gcc -shared -o clib.so clib.c -fPIC

clib.o: clib.c
    gcc -Wall -Werror clib.c -fPIC

test: clib.so
    chmod 777 pyclib.py
    python pyclib.py 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: I mean, "unpythonic" isn't exactly an "error", but ... why not use a list comprehension here then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is what you're after, but, you can have a list comprehension, and then 'expand' the list using the asterisk operator:

```
args=(ctypes.c_char_p * len( sys.argv ))( *[str.encode(i) for i in sys.argv] )
```

Also, this is quite ugly from a readability point of view. I'd split the one-liner to make things clear for the reader:

```
C_charPointer_array = ctypes.c_char_p * len( sys.argv )
EncodedArgsList     = [str.encode( i ) for i in sys.argv]
args                = C_charPointer_array( *EncodedArgsList )
```

Comment: It's perfect, thank you ! I didn't know you could expand a list using the asterisk operator neither you could split the ugly line.

Comment: @HugoCastaing Oh yes. You can unpack dictionaries too, into keyword=value arguments. See here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists